# How to synchronize two view in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to do this: In my GUI, I have one JTable with a custom model, and in other part of the GUI, I have one panel where i draw some arrows. I want to "synchronize this two view. So let's say if we have 5 rows in my JTable, I will draw 5 arrows in the panel of arrows. If I make a modification in the number of row, I must have the same number of row. 
So I'm trying to use Design Pattern Observer.

To make simple, I try to provide an example computable in one file: 
I create n buttons in my first Panel (ButtonPanel) and I create n label in the second panel (LabelButton).

**The problem is : How to synchronize the number of label withthe number of label with DP Observer**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

interface Observer {
    public void update(Subject subject, int number);
}

interface Subject {
    public void addObserver(Observer observer);

    public void delObserver(Observer observer);

    public void notifyObservers();
}

class SynchronizeNumber implements Subject {
    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;

    private int numberSync;

    public SynchronizeNumber() {
        super();
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    }

    public SynchronizeNumber(int numberSync) {
        super();
        this.numberSync = numberSync;
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);

    }

    @Override
    public void delObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer o : observers) {
            o.update(this, this.numberSync);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the number
     */
    public int getNumberSync() {
        return numberSync;
    }

    /**
     * @param number
     *            the number to set
     */
    public void setNumberSync(int numberSync) {
        this.numberSync = numberSync;
        notifyObservers();
    }
}

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private int numberButton;

    public ButtonPanel() {
        super();
    }

    public ButtonPanel(int numberButton) {
        this.numberButton = numberButton;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberButton; i++)
            this.add(new JButton("" + i));
    }

    /**
     * @return the numberLabel
     */
    public int getNumberButton() {
        return numberButton;
    }

    /**
     * @param numberLabel
     *            the numberLabel to set
     */
    public void setNumberButton(int numberButton) {
        this.numberButton = numberButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Subject subject, int number) {
        if (subject instanceof SynchronizeNumber) {
            SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = (SynchronizeNumber) subject;
            numberButton = synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync();
            System.out.println("ButtonPanel, numberButton: " + numberButton);
        }
    }
}

class LabelPanel extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private int numberLabel;

    public LabelPanel() {
        super();
    }

    public LabelPanel(int numberLabel) {
        super();
        this.numberLabel = numberLabel;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberLabel; i++)
            this.add(new JLabel("label numbe: " + i));
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Subject subject, int number) {
        if (subject instanceof SynchronizeNumber) {
            SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = (SynchronizeNumber) subject;
            numberLabel = synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync();
            System.out.println("LabelPanel, numberLabel: " + numberLabel);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the numberLabel
     */
    public int getNumberLabel() {
        return numberLabel;
    }

    /**
     * @param numberLabel
     *            the numberLabel to set
     */
    public void setNumberLabel(int numberLabel) {
        this.numberLabel = numberLabel;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        // create an subject synchronizeNumber
        SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = new SynchronizeNumber();

        // set number to 1
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(1);

        //create observers buttonPanel and labelPanel 
        ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync());
        LabelPanel labelPanel = new LabelPanel(synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync());

        // add buttonPanel and labelPanel as observers
        synchronizeNumber.addObserver(buttonPanel);
        synchronizeNumber.addObserver(labelPanel);

        // make a change manually
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(4);
        f.add(buttonPanel);
        f.add(labelPanel);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

edit: I use my own DP Observer and not from the API because multiple extending is not possible

Comment: *"So let's say if we have 5 rows in my JTable, I will draw 5 arrows in the panel of arrows."* It is strictly necessary use Observer Pattern? It is an assignment or a requirement? If not, then it would be easier implement a [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to update your panel every time a row is inserted/deleted from your table model.

Comment: I use Observer pattern because I think it is the best solution. I have two classes and I want a minimun dependency between the two classes.

Comment: @dic19 isn't a listener the observer pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I use Observer pattern because I think it is the best solution.*

Swing is an Event Driven API and acts pretty much like an Observer Pattern in the sense that there are events and listeners subscribed to listen those events. For instance [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) component dispatches an [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) every time it is pressed and notifies to subscribed [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)s that something happened.

With the same principle, is responsibility of [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) to dispatch a [TableModelEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) every time data has been changed (rows added/deleted, cells updated, etc) and notify subscribed [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html)s in such events.

You can use this fact to accomplish your main goal:

> *So let's say if we have 5 rows in my JTable, I will draw 5 arrows in
>   the panel of arrows.*

1. Create a `JPanel` with the ability to draw many arrows as you wish. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) lesson.
2. Attach a `TableModelListener` to your `TableModel` in order to repaint your `JPanel` when rows are inserted/deleted.

---

> *I have two classes and I want a minimun dependency between the two
>   classes.*

If you follow my suggestions, you should be able to create an independent and reusable `JPanel` like this:

```
class MyCustomPanel extends JPanel {

    private int numberOfArrows = 0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // never forget to call super.paintComponent(g)
        Graphics graphics = g.create();
        int y = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfArrows; i++) {                
            graphics.drawLine(10, y, getWidth() - 10, y); // instead of lines just draw your arrows
            y += 10;
        }
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Public method to set the number of arrows that has to be drawn.
     * @param arrows 
     */
    public void setNumberOfArrows(int arrows) {
        numberOfArrows = arrows;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return isPreferredSizeSet() 
             ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(200,200);
    }
}
```

This way your panel can take the number of arrows from the outside independently on how it is determined (it could be number of rows in a table model, number of elements in a list, a fixed value, whatever you want).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it exactly as you wanted:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

interface Observer {
    public void update(Subject subject, int number);
}

interface Subject {
    public void addObserver(Observer observer);

    public void delObserver(Observer observer);

    public void notifyObservers();
}

class SynchronizeNumber implements Subject {
    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;

    private int numberSync;

    public SynchronizeNumber() {
        super();
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    }

    public SynchronizeNumber(int numberSync) {
        super();
        this.numberSync = numberSync;
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);

    }

    @Override
    public void delObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer o : observers) {
            o.update(this, this.numberSync);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the number
     */
    public int getNumberSync() {
        return numberSync;
    }

    /**
     * @param number
     *            the number to set
     */
    public void setNumberSync(int numberSync) {
        this.numberSync = numberSync;
        notifyObservers();
    }
}

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private int numberButton;

    public ButtonPanel() {
        super();
    }

    public ButtonPanel(int numberButton) {
        this.numberButton = numberButton;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberButton; i++)
            this.add(createButton(i));
    }

    /**
     * @return the numberLabel
     */
    public int getNumberButton() {
        return numberButton;
    }

    /**
     * @param numberLabel
     *            the numberLabel to set
     */
    public void setNumberButton(int numberButton) {
        this.numberButton = numberButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Subject subject, int number) {
        if (subject instanceof SynchronizeNumber) {
            SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = (SynchronizeNumber) subject;
            int diff = numberButton + (number - numberButton);
            // if diff and numberButton are equal do nothing
            if (diff < numberButton) {
                for (int i = numberButton - 1; i >= diff; i--) {
                    this.remove(this.getComponent(i));
                }
            } else if (diff > numberButton) {
                for (int i = numberButton; i < diff; i++) {
                    this.add(createButton(i));
                }
            }
            numberButton = number;
            System.out.println("ButtonPanel, numberButton: " + numberButton);
        }
    }

    private JButton createButton(int i) {
        return new JButton("" + ++i);
    }
}

class LabelPanel extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private int numberLabel;

    public LabelPanel() {
        super();
    }

    public LabelPanel(int numberLabel) {
        super();
        this.numberLabel = numberLabel;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberLabel; i++)
            this.add(createLabel(i));
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Subject subject, int number) {
        if (subject instanceof SynchronizeNumber) {
            SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = (SynchronizeNumber) subject;
            int diff = numberLabel + (number - numberLabel);
            // if diff and numberButton are equal do nothing
            if (diff < numberLabel) {
                for (int i = numberLabel - 1; i >= diff; i--) {
                    this.remove(this.getComponent(i));
                }
            } else if (diff > numberLabel) {
                for (int i = numberLabel; i < diff; i++) {
                    this.add(createLabel(i));
                }
            }
            numberLabel = number;
            System.out.println("LabelPanel, numberLabel: " + numberLabel);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the numberLabel
     */
    public int getNumberLabel() {
        return numberLabel;
    }

    /**
     * @param numberLabel
     *            the numberLabel to set
     */
    public void setNumberLabel(int numberLabel) {
        this.numberLabel = numberLabel;
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(int i) {
        return new JLabel("label name:" + ++i);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        // create an subject synchronizeNumber
        SynchronizeNumber synchronizeNumber = new SynchronizeNumber();

        // set number to 1
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(1);

        // create observers buttonPanel and labelPanel
        ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync());
        LabelPanel labelPanel = new LabelPanel(synchronizeNumber.getNumberSync());

        // add buttonPanel and labelPanel as observers
        synchronizeNumber.addObserver(buttonPanel);
        synchronizeNumber.addObserver(labelPanel);

        // make a change manually
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(4);

        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(3);
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(11);
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(5);
        synchronizeNumber.setNumberSync(7);

        f.add(buttonPanel);
        f.add(labelPanel);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```