# How to draw the exact number of line in my gui?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw the exact number of line in my gui. So I use a TableModelListener to listen the number of row in my Jtable and I manage to display the number of row each time when i add a new row in my table.

**Problem :** But now, I want to draw x lines in my gui when i have x rows in my jtable. I try to put a TableModelListerner like above but it's not working.

Thanks for helping. I sorry to put a lot of classes but I want also to learn to make a reusable code and to learn java swing.

[image]

**class Test**

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));

        TablePanel tablePanel = new TablePanel();
        ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        DrawTwoSameDrawPanel drawPanels = new DrawTwoSameDrawPanel();

        f.add(tablePanel);
        f.add(buttonPanel);
        f.add(drawPanels);

        f.setSize(800, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

**class MyTableModel**

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = { "RowListener", "B", "C" };
    private Object[][] data = { { "x", "xx", "xxx" }, { "y", "yy", "yyy" }, { "z", "zz", "zzz" } };

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return data[0][col].getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = aValue;
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(Object[][] data) {
        int index = 0;
        int nbRow = this.getRowCount();
        int nbCol = this.getColumnCount();

        Object temp[][] = this.data;
        this.data = new Object[nbRow + 1][nbCol];

        for (Object[] value : temp)
            this.data[index++] = value;

        this.data[index] = data;
        temp = null;

        this.fireTableDataChanged();

    }

}
```

**class ButtonPanel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;

    public ButtonPanel() {
        super();

        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
        button = new JButton("Update");
        this.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("hello console");

                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to update drawPanel ?", "Question",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("console : YES");
                    updatePanels();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("console : NO");
            }

        });
    }

    public void updatePanels() {
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();        
        drawPanel.revalidate();
        drawPanel.repaint();

    }
}
```

**class DrawPanel**

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements TableModelListener{

    private MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    private int numberOfLine = 0;

    public DrawPanel() {
        super();
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics graphics = g.create();
        int y = 10;

        /////////don't work 
        RowListener rowListener = new RowListener(model);
        numberOfLine = rowListener.getNumberOfRow();
        //////////

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLine; i++) {
            graphics.drawLine(10, y, getWidth() - 10, y);
            y += 10;
        }
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    public void setNumberOfArrows(int arrows) {
        numberOfLine = arrows;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getNumberOfArrows() {
        return numberOfLine;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return isPreferredSizeSet() ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

     @Override
     public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
     int numberOfRow = model.getRowCount();
     this.setNumberOfArrows(numberOfRow);
     System.out.println("numberOfRow: " + numberOfRow);

     }

    class RowListener implements TableModelListener {
        private MyTableModel model;
        private int numberOfRow;

        public RowListener(MyTableModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            model.addTableModelListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
            numberOfRow = model.getRowCount();          
            System.out.println("numberOfRow: " + numberOfRow);
        }

        public int getNumberOfRow() {
            return numberOfRow;
        }

        public void setNumberOfRow(int numberOfRow) {
            this.numberOfRow = numberOfRow;
        }
    }

}
```

**class TablePanel**

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel {

private MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
private JTable table = new JTable(model);
private int nbRow = 0;

private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Row");

public TablePanel() {
    super();
    this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.orange));
    this.add(table);
    this.add(addButton);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            model.addRow(new Object[][] { { "u", "u", "u" }, { "v", "v", "vy" }, { "w", "w", "w" } });
            model.fireTableStructureChanged();
            nbRow = model.getRowCount();
            System.out.println("nbRow: " + nbRow);

        }
    });

    this.add(createDisplayNbRowPanel());

}

public JPanel createDisplayNbRowPanel() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JLabel("number of row : "));
    NbRowView nbRowView = new NbRowView(model);
    p.add(nbRowView);
    p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));

    return p;
}

public int getNbRow() {
    return nbRow;
}

public void setNbRow(int nbRow) {
    this.nbRow = nbRow;
}

class NbRowView extends JLabel implements TableModelListener {

    private MyTableModel model;

    public NbRowView(MyTableModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.addTableModelListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
        int nbOfRow = model.getRowCount();
        this.setText(nbOfRow + "");
        DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        drawPanel.setNumberOfArrows(nbOfRow);

    }

}

}
```

**class DrawTwoSameDrawPanel**

```
public class DrawTwoSameDrawPanel extends JPanel {

private DrawPanel drawPanel_1 = new DrawPanel();
private DrawPanel drawPanel_2 = new DrawPanel();

public DrawTwoSameDrawPanel() {
    super();
    this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green));
    this.add(drawPanel_1);
    this.add(drawPanel_2);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just query the table model for the number of (visible) elements? That way you'd get the number of lines to draw.

Comment: Btw, "it's not working" is not very helpful. You might want to elaborate on _in what way_ it is not working, e.g. what you expect and what you get instead, maybe supported by a few examples.

Comment: You'll probably want a `ChangeListener` to listen for selection changes, or maybe a `TableModelListener` to listen for Table data changes?

Comment: 1) Really too complicated structure and a lot of code. 2)You always create new instances where that doesn't need to do: `drawPanel = new DrawPanel();`, `RowListener rowListener = new RowListener(model);` 3) Seems that doesn't work because of `updatePanels()` method in which you create a new one panel, but display old. `drawPanel = new DrawPanel();` - doesn't replace visible instance on `JFrame`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to draw x lines in my gui when i have x rows in my jtable.*

Looking at your previous question: [How to synchronize two view in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886172/how-to-synchronize-two-view-in-java-swing) you have implemented the `paintComponent()` method of your `DrawPanel` pretty well, but you still need to decouple this from table model. As other developers said your code is large and complicated and you need to better organize it:

1. Create a reusable panel as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886172/how-to-synchronize-two-view-in-java-swing?noredirect=1#comment38684049_24886172)
2. When you create a new instance of your table model, attach a new [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to call `setNumberOfArrows()` method, that will repaint your panel as you wish.

For instance:

```
class GuiClass {

    private DrawPanel drawPanel;

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() { // Anonymous class
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if(e.getType() == TableModelEvent.INSERT || e.getType() == TableModelEvent.DELETE) {
                    int rows = ((TableModel)e.getSource()).getRowCount();
                    drawPanel.setNumberOfArrows(rows);
                }
            }
        });
        // rest of your GUI code here
    }
}
```

***Note:*** Java provides a good mechanism to avoid create an excesive number of classes to implement interfaces or extend from other classes: [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

About your table model, please note it looks like [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) pretty much, so you may want to use that class instead of create your own (if it fits your requirements of course).

Additionaly, the implementation of [getColumnClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29) method should never look up for data to retrieve a value, you should be able to return the correct class since you know what kind of data your table model will contain.

Finally your `addRow(Object[][] row)` method doesn't make sense since you probably want to add a single row to your table model, not row and columns. I think it should be `addRow(Object[] row)` (note single-dimension array as parameter). Having said this it should look like this:

```
public void addRow(Object[] row) {
    // add row here
    int rowIndex = data.length;
    fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
}
```

See [AbstractTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html):

- [fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow,int
  lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29)
- [fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int
  lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: You are welcome :) If you still have doubts or don't know how to put all pieces together just let me know. I could post an example to help you. @user3748551